# How can I write BLOBs in android FAST?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I have an app that downloads many images that are about 50k to 100k in size. The full database can be anywhere from 50MB to 500MB.

We are currently using sqlite, but it has slow inserts. We did a test writing files and that was slow as well. It seems to be taking about 300 to 800ms per image to write - which comes out to about 250kb/sec (slower than the network speed). I did a benchmark with A1 benchmark and it says my write speed is 14MB/sec, so i'm not sure why my app is so slow?

Here are the primary requirements:
1) Fast writes
2) Fast reads/lookups via an custom integer key (this can be converted a file path for individual files)
3) Prevents user from easily accessing the images (if we save as images they can connect the external storage to their computer and browser, but we can write the files in reverse byte order)

hopefully we can still use the sqllite solution, as i like one file, but either way it seems like a storage issue?

Comment: you know you dont have to save images to the publicly available sd card, you can save them to your apps directory so they cant access them unless the user has a rooted phone. saving images in sqlite is not a good solution

Comment: Save them to your app's storage directory (e.g. `context.getFilesDir()`) and just store paths in the database.

Comment: I agree, SQLite is nowhere near a good solution. Files are OK, but you have to save them right. We need a piece of code to understand how you're saving the files. Mind that this kind of operation is purely Java, so we need to know what kind of `Writer` are you using and such.

Comment: "i'm not sure why my app is so slow?" -- use Traceview and determine where your problem lies. Beyond that, we would need a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to suggest improvements to what you are already doing.

Comment: see https://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html, they say that (in theory) BLOBS < 100kB should be in general faster than separate files

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I think you are better off using the private memory storage for the actual images. This will have better speed then storing BLOBs in SQLite.

If you still need to keep a DB, for example for complex image searches or such, I suggest you just replace the BLOB field in your DB with a string with the actual location of the image file.

Another solution is to keep the images as app assets, but this assumes the images are always the same and can't change dynamically, and I doubt this is your use case.